# Validating Form - Sum of varied rows in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, validation, coldfusion

I am having trouble figuring out the best approach on how to validate when a user submits a specific form. Depending on the user, he/she will be able to edit either a region with states, or the entire nation, with all of the regions. So I need to validate that what they enter in for all of their states equals their regional allotment (for each column). And if a user had national access, I need to make sure that all of the regions add up to the national total.

I am coding in HTML and Coldfusion, but if using javascript for the validation, that should not matter. The results will be dynamic so I do not want to hard code any of the validation since the query is dynamic. In some cases all of the rows from 3-13 will equal row 1, with 3-12 equalling row 2. In some cases rows 2-7 should equal row 1. Each case might be different.

Here is my form display code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#getdata.recordcount#">
<tr id="editrow#i#" style="background-color:##f0f0f0">
    <td>#getdata.location[i]#</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="initial#i#" name="initial#i#" value="#numberFormat(getdata.initial[i],'9,999')#"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="recon#i#" name="recon#i#" value="#numberFormat(getdata.recon[i],'9,999')#"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cdr#i#" name="cdr#i#" value="#numberFormat(getdata.cdr[i],'9,999')#"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="other#i#" name="other#i#" value="#numberFormat(getdata.cdr[i],'9,999')#"></td>
</tr>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: If they are entering numbers, use javascript to take away the submit button if they don't follow the business rules of your application.  Also, only show the user what they are allowed to see.

Comment: They are only going to see what they are allowed. My question is about how to validate the sums to make sure they equal the total allotment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include the hidden field named recordCount in your form. You may then validate the form on the action page as follows:

```
<cfset recordCount = form.recordCount>

<cfset validationValInitial = 0>
<cfset validationValRecon = 0>
<cfset validationValCDR = 0>
<cfset validationValOther = 0>

<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="fieldname">
    <!--- Use first 3 letters to identify each category of fields --->
    <cfswitch expression="#left(fieldname,3)#">
        <cfcase value="ini"><!--- initial1, initial2, ... --->
            <cfloop from="1" to="#recordCount#" index="rowNo">
                <cfif rowNo GTE 3 and rowNo LTE 13>
                    <cfset validationValInitial = validationValInitial + form['initial' & rowNo]>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop> 
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="rec"><!--- recon1, recon2, ... --->

        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="cdr"><!--- cdr1, cdr2, ... --->

        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="oth"><!---other1, other2, ... --->

        </cfcase>
    </cfswitch>
</cfloop>

/*
Here, I have assumed that the validation rule for the fields initial1, initial2, ... is that the sum of the values in rows 3 to 13 equals the value in row 1. Use this as an example, and work out the rest. 
*/

<cfif validationValInitial EQ form.initial1>
<!--- valid --->
<cfelse>
</cfif>
```